# Is it possible to send dynamic emails from Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, amp-html, amp-email

'm building an internal request-approval system for my company, and the best scenario I'd like to develop is using the amp dynamic emails in Gmail (our company relies on G Suite services).

I made some few tests, and while sending through https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/ is working fine, when I try to send from GAS the amp content is not showing (Developer settings already enabled, my own address is white-listed). Knowing that GAS has some various limitations, I'd like to know if it's even possible to send automated dynamic emails.

```js
function doGet(e) {          
  var body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('body').evaluate().getContent()

  GmailApp.sendEmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, new Date(), body, { htmlBody : body})          
}
```

the html body

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html ⚡4email>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
      <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
      <style amp-custom>
        h1 {
          margin: 1rem;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <body>
  <amp-img src="https://placekitten.com/800/400"
           alt="Welcome"
           width="800"
           height="400">
  </amp-img>
</body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It’s possible to automate the sending of emails. It’s not clear about what you mean by dynamic emails.

Comment: Could you share what you tried?

Comment: @Cooper dynamic emails are a specific new feature of emails, available in Gmail, but that have rather strict criteria and registration process
https://www.blog.google/products/gmail/take-action-and-stay-up-to-date-with-dynamic-email-in-gmail/
documentation https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail

Comment: @lamblichus updated the question with the code

Comment: Have you ruled out other issues? Were you able to receive amp emails through any other methods?

Comment: Are you fine using SES as the email relay? I think Gmail doesn't allow to send dynamic email from Gmail. I had personally tried and failed.

Comment: @TheMaster yes, I was able through https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/. But the same content sent through GAS (see code over) is not working.

Comment: Try whether directly sending email using gmail api works using apiexplorer(http request). Also try `amp4email` instead of `⚡4email`

Comment: @TheMaster change to amp4email doesn't sort any effect. I don't know apiexplorer, just in case I stress one more time that I'm searching for a GAS solution

Comment: You can try the api [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#try-it). If it works there,  you can make it work here in GAS through advanced Google services. On reading guidelines again, it seems you need to [register](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/register) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMP for Email requires the AMP to be a separate part in a `multipart/alternative` MIME tree with `text/x-amp-html` as the `Content-Type`. See [Structure and rendering of AMP emails](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-structure/?format=email) for more information.

The [documentation for `GmailApp.sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) has the following explanation:

> Sends an email message with optional arguments. **The email can contain plain text or an HTML body.** The size of the email (including headers, but excluding attachments) is quota limited.

Therefore, it's not currently possible to include the required `text/x-amp-html` part in the email body using this API. The code you have now is putting the AMP code inside the `text/html` part which email clients will treat as regular HTML email, likely resulting in stripping the required markup and scripts.